# Gunicorn autorestart causing errors

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn

I am running gunicorn in async mode behind a nginx reverse proxy. Both are in separate docker containers on the same VM in the host network and everything is running fine as long as I don't configure max_requests to autorestart workers after a certain amount of requests. With autorestart configured the reboot of workers is not handled correctly, throwing errors and causing failed responses. I need this settings to fix problems with memory leaks and prevent gunicorn and other application components from crashing.

Gunicorn log:

```
2020-08-07 06:55:23 [1438] [INFO] Autorestarting worker after current request.
2020-08-07 06:55:23 [1438] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mapproxy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 65, in handle
    util.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/opt/mapproxy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 625, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/mapproxy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 38, in handle
    listener_name = listener.getsockname()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Gunicorn is running with the following configuration:

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:8081'
worker_class = 'eventlet' 
workers = 8
timeout = 60
no_sendfile = True
max_requests = 1000
max_requests_jitter = 500
```

Comment: When serving through gunicorn the error traceback can be a lot less useful. It's too generic and doesn't tell much what exactly broke. Try run without gunicorn and see if you get any error tracebacks there.

Comment: @TinNguyen I don't understand. From what I understand and see in the stacktrace, this error is caused by Gunicorn itself. What do you mean by running without gunicorn?

Comment: I don't know what your gunicorn is wrapping around. It can be flask, django, etc. Take for instance this project: https://github.com/nntin/twitter-backend I can execute the project with `gunicorn app:app` or I can execute the project with `python app.py`. When I have made a mistake in `app.py` the traceback from gunicorn won't show the call stack with the line of code in `app.py`. But when I execute it in python it will show the proper full call stack.

Comment: Gunicorn is wrapping around a wsgi app [mapproxy](https://github.com/mapproxy/mapproxy). But I am really not seeing how the app itself is playing in here. The app itself doesn't crash or show any errors and it's working fine while running without  `max_requests` set. It's also running fine using different wsgi servers.

Comment: This setting was causing connection reset issues with sync workers for us, but apparently it's not really meant for production: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/3038#issuecomment-1887073067